# Rails: Capitalize characters after certain string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, character, capitalize

Using: Rails 3.0.3.

I have a string that could be seen as this one:

```
<p>hello, how are you? oh, that's nice! i am glad you are fine. i am too.<br />i am glad to have met you.</p>
```

I want each character following any of `<p> <br /> ! ?` . to be capitalized. Basically make the string above look good.

Is there a standard functionality for that? What should I do?

ps. Tried to bold the characters in question, but it didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off Niklaos answer, I've improved it slightly to take into account the period and keeping spacing intact in the rendered HTML.

```
str.gsub(/(\<p\>|\<br \/\>|[?!.])([\s]*)([[:alpha:]]{1})/) {"#{$1}#{$2}#{$3.capitalize}"}
```

Edit: Added punctuation characters to be in a single character class, captured all in between whitespace to preserve spacing.  Much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Using Nokogiri you can have any markup around the text, and it breaks on the <br /> etc.

```
ng = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment("<p>hello, how are you? oh, that's nice! i am glad you are fine. i am too.<br />i am glad to have met you.</p>")
ng.traverse{|n| (n.content = n.content.gsub(/(.*?)([\.|\!|\?])/) { " #{$1.strip.capitalize}#{$2}" }.strip) if n.text?}
ng.to_s
```

gives :

```
"<p>Hello, how are you? Oh, that's nice! I am glad you are fine. I am too.<br>I am glad to have met you.</p>"
```

I used strip twice, first because a sentence after stop/question/exclamation will have white space and not capitalize otherwise, then to put the spacing back I added a space before each sentence - the second strip removes the generated space at the start of the final output.

Comment: Mark: I never got to try this function since I tried Lester's first, and it worked. But still, thank you so very much for helping out on the issue. It seems like you contributed just as much. Thanks!!!

Comment: Haha, googled the same thing 5 years later, tried the first solution, again, and continued to this one, again, and was happy to see it worked. Wanted to write a comment, only to realize I actually had done this 5 years before and wrote a comment just like that one :)

Answer (score 0):

capitalize is the method you are looking for. although you have to do it for each sentence. You can easily parse that with nokogiri if you have to though

Comment: Can Nokogiri be used to find what is a "sentence" in this string? Can it do: "if after ! then capitalize"...?

Answer (score 0):

Hum I feel like it's time to call super Regex :)

```
str.gsub(/(\<p\>|\<br \/\>|! |\? )(.{1})/) {"#{$1}#{$2.capitalize}"}
```

That should to the job.

Note: this can be improved to have more flexibility.