# Alter regex markup to not separate float numbers (like 2.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I was looking for a solution to a regex problem in Rails I had and an answer on a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650753/rails-capitalize-characters-after-certain-string/7657513#comment65259528_7657513) lead me 90% of the path to the answer. Basically, what I would like to do is to have a ruby/rails script that will format a messy text in terms of capitalizing every letter after a "./,/!/?". This code by "Mark S"

```
ng = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment("<p>hello, how are you? oh, that's nice! i am glad you are fine. i am too.<br />i am glad to have met you.</p>")
ng.traverse{|n| (n.content = n.content.gsub(/(.*?)([\.|\!|\?])/) { " #{$1.strip.capitalize}#{$2}" }.strip) if n.text?}
ng.to_s
```

The only issue I have with this code, and it is a big issue, is that **the code adds a space in between float numbers like "2.0"**, making a text like:

```
there is a cat in the hat.it has a 2.0 inch tail!
isn't that awesome?!I think so.
```

Become

```
There is a cat i the hat. It has a 2. 0 inch tail! 
Isn't that awesome?! I think so.
```

where I obviously want it to be:

```
There is a cat i the hat. It has a 2.0 inch tail! 
Isn't that awesome?! I think so.
```

Any suggestions on how to alter this text, for example so that any "." will be ignored by this code?

Comment: Does [**`[.?!]\s*[a-z]`**](http://rubular.com/r/pXLeg4hqkH) help you?

Comment: Should work as long as you don't have to support spanish input such as  `¿qué?¿cuánto?`.

Comment: Use `.gsub(/([.?!])(\p{Ll})/) { "#{$1} #{$2.capitalize}" }`. However, there is a problem with abbreviations (as usual in these cases), like `i.e.`, `e.g.`, etc. Then there are words like `iPhone`, `iCloud`, `eSklep`, and so on. Regex is kind of blind :( Have a look at what this approach can lead to: https://ideone.com/Fq4srn

Comment: Thanks...I tried Jan's approach and it seems to be working but now I can't recreate the error even with the old code. I am currently troubleshooting that.

Comment: Wiktor's answer does not capitalize the first letter, it will result in: "there is a cat in the hat. It has a 2.0 inch tail!" but works otherwise.

Comment: Try `s.gsub(/(\A|[.?!])(\p{Ll})/) { Regexp.last_match(1).length > 0 ? "#{$1} #{$2.capitalize}" : "#{$2.capitalize}" }` - https://ideone.com/ECEUpW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to capitalize any lowercase letter at the beginning of the string or after `.`, `!`, or `?`.

Use

```
s.gsub(/(\A|[.?!])(\p{Ll})/) { Regexp.last_match(1).length > 0 ? "#{$1} #{$2.capitalize}" : "#{$2.capitalize}" }
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/ECEUpW)

**Pattern details**:

- `(\A|[.?!])`  - Group 1 capturing the start of string location (empty string) or a `.`, `?`, or `!`
- `(\p{Ll})` - Group 2 capturing any Unicode lowercase letter

Inside the replacement, we check if Group 1 value is not empty, and if it is, we just return the capitalized letter. Else, return the punctuation, a space, and the capitalized letter.

**NOTE**: However, there is a problem with abbreviations (as usual in these cases), like `i.e.`, `e.g.`, etc. Then there are words like `iPhone`, `iCloud`, `eSklep`, and so on.

Comment: This works quite well when I try it in the console but crashes my app when I try it live (complaining that Regexp.last_match(1) = nil which makes nil.length crash). That is just peculiar and perhaps outside of this scope. One thing that doesn't work with this is however if there is a space between the period and the next sentence as in "i saw a cat. it was black". How would you solve that?

Comment: Also, I am using utf-8 strings, maybe that causes problems for me?

Comment: UTF8 should not be the problem. What if you also check if the `Regexp.last_match(1)` is not `nil`? `Regexp.last_match(1) != nil && Regexp.last_match(1).length > 0 ?`

Comment: Check  https://ideone.com/Wt28kf. Do you want to preserve the spaces between the end punctuation and the uppercased letter? If not, [the code](https://ideone.com/Wt28kf) should work.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! Now it complains about $2 being nil => undefined method `capitalize' for nil:NilClass for "#{$2.capitalize}"

Comment: I can see it works on my example string so let me get back with a better example...

Comment: Group 2 is obligatory, it cannot be nil.

Comment: I finally realized the error, it turned out that in my app the "string" was actually a ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer which caused me a lot of trouble. Your code works now, thanks!